# Enable Field Validation Error in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

On a button click I am hiding all the field validator error by :

```
$(".field-validation-error").hide()
```

However I would need this to be activated for some of the fields but not for all.

Let's say I would need this to be activated for the following control.

```
<td>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BookTitle, new { @id = "PTitle" })
</td>
<td style="color: Red; display: block; margin-right:20px;">

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BookTitle, "", new { @id = "pTitleModelError" })
</td>
```

I tried enabling it like this using Jquery,

```
$("#pTitleModelError .field-validation-error").show();
```

Without any luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: With the spacing your selector is currently looking for a child of #pTitleModelError remove the spacing in between

Comment: @PatsyIssa somehow it is not working.. In a button click I was trying to hide all other erroe messages except this. As of now it is like this. `$(".field-validation-error").hide();
        $("#pTitleModelError.field-validation-error").show();` Its not validating that field.

Comment: Are the elements nested in the same td ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to hide all elements with .field-validation-error  and show one with pTitleModelError
Try...

```
$("#pTitleModelError").show();
```

Comment: he wants to show the #pTitleModelError that has the class field-validation-error